# How does a mobile WordPress theme differ from a simple theme?

Tags: theme-development, mobile

1. What should be taken care of while coding a mobile theme as compared to a simple one?
2. Is there any tutorial available that teaches how to develop a **mobile** theme from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not a "wordpress" specific, it's just the css. You just give it a css for mobile browsers. That's it.

here are few good readings on how to get about the css for mobile:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying.html
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/responsive-web-design-a-visual-guide/

if you still have some questions, feel free to ask. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to use (or take a look at) [Carringtion Mobile](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-edition/). It's developed by a known Author with lots of reputation since a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this series helpful is creating your own mobile theme.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jqtouch-mobile-wordpress-1/

A good idea would be to work a mobile stylesheet into your current theme. As one of the links added before this answer will stipulate, making your theme responsive is the way things are moving these days.